# Audio элемент в javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. Объясните пожалуйста почем не работает:
JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("audio").hide();
    $("li a").eq(0).bind("click", function () {
        $("audio").hide();
        $("audio:eq(0)").show();
    });
    $("li a").eq(1).bind("click", function () {
        $("audio").css("display", "none");
        $("audio:eq(1)").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#audio-player").mediaelementplayer({
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        features: ["playpause", "volume", "progress"],
        audioVolume: "horizontal",
        audioWidth: 400;
        audioHeight: 120
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id = "songs">

    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href = "#"
id = "song"> Now you see me </a>
</li>
    <li>
    <a href = "#"
id = "song1"> Flute </a>
</li>
    </div>
<div class = "audio-player">
<audio class = "first_song" id = "audio-player" src = "Brian_Tyler_-_01._Now_You_See_Me_OST-HD_Illyuziya_obmana_Now_You_See_Me_2013_(get-tune.net).mp3" type = "audio/mp3
" controls = "
controls "></audio>
<audio class = "
second_song " id = "
audio - player " src = "
New_World_Sound_Thomas_Newson_ - _Flute_Original_Mix_(iPlayer.fm).mp3 " type = "
audio / mp3 " controls = "
controls "></audio>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div.audio-player {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

audio {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 7;
    -moz-border-radius: 7;
    -khtml-border-radius: 7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7;
    -o-border-radius: 7;
    background-color: Red;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#songs {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 45%;
}

#song {
    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: Yellow;
    color: Black;
    display: inline;
}

#song1 {
    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: Yellow;
    color: Black;
    display: inline;
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я не совсем про это. У меня не получается скрыть полосу воспроизведения.

Comment: Какую полосу воспроизведения Вы хотите скрыть? Код (с моими доработками) работает исправно. Только нужна еще одна поправка: **на странице может быть только 1 элемент с одинаковым id**. Используйте класс или тег.

Answer (score 3):

Заглядывайте в консоль, там иногда пишут интересные вещи. У Вас в JS коде опечатка (вместо запятой - точка с запятой). Верный вариант:

```
$("#audio-player").mediaelementplayer({  
    alwaysShowControls: true,  
    features: ["playpause", "volume", "progress"],  
    audioVolume:  "horizontal",  
    audioWidth: 400, 
    audioHeight: 120  
});
```